# What is the behavior of the engine customized for Simplified Chinese, when requesting Traditional Chinese translation?

Tags: microsoft-translator

As you cannot have both Chinese under same category and label, what is the expected behavior of engine customized for *zh-Hans*, when requesting *zh-Hant* translation?

Will it first translate into *zh-Hans*, then transcribe into *zh-Hant*? If this is the case, will it use the customized engine, or the generic one? How will it be charged?

Comment: Interesting question, did you ever get an answer?  Definitely it could use the custom engine and then just convert the chars.  If it's not, then you could do that unilaterally, but it would be a pity to have to double-pay and also add complexity and latency.

Answer (score -1):

Custom translator (CT) allows you to train and deploy en-us to zh-Hans custom model. When you make request to your custom model, CT translates the zh-Hant text to en-us first then uses your custom model to return the translation. The accuracy and fluency of the returned translation will be heavily influenced by the cleanliness and amount of training data set used. See [Training a model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/custom-translator/training-and-model). If you don't have enough data to train a custom model, I highly recommend using the general [Microsoft Translator API v3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/translator-info-overview).

Once the custom model is deployed, anyone can make translation requests to the model but must provide own subscription key for charges.

-Mohamed

Comment: Maybe I didn't state it clearly, but the question is about en -> zh-Hant, when you have en -> zh-Hans custom engine deployed.